# PdfBox: issues when creating pdf from bmp

Tags: java, bitmap, pdfbox

When generating a PDF form BMP the result is allways curios.

Input "hellowworld.bmp"

[image: Inputfile: helloworld.bmp]

Output (only the relevant part)
[image: resultfile]

- why is there a loss of quality
- why is it repeated three times
- why is there a black square ( green Frame)

Heres how i test it:

```
@Test
public final void testWriteSingleBMPtoPDF() throws IOException {
    Assert.assertTrue("File existst", TestFileHelper.getBMP(BMPS.HELLOWORLD).exists());
    Assert.assertTrue("File readable", TestFileHelper.getBMP(BMPS.HELLOWORLD).canRead());
    ArrayList<File> doc = new ArrayList<EncodedPage>();
    doc.add(createPage(BMPS.HELLOWORLD));
    File result = null;
    try {
        result = ConvertPDF.bmpToPDF(doc);
    } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Assert.assertTrue("File existst", result.exists());
    Assert.assertTrue("File readable", result.canRead());
    System.out.println("Please Check >"+result+"<");
}
```

Heres the part of my java implementation

```
public static File bmpToPDF(ArrayList<File> inputDoc)
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        String saveTo = "C:\\temp\\" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf";
        for (File bmpPage : inputDoc) {
            PDPage page = null;
            PDXObjectImage ximage = null;
            page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(page);
            BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(bmpPage);
            ximage = new PDPixelMap(document, awtImage);
            PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
            content.drawImage(ximage, 0, 0);
            content.close();
        }
        document.save(saveTo);
        document.close();
return new File(saveTo) ;
```

Version of Apache PDFBox is 1.7.1

Comment: I am having this same problem, what did you do to fix?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I have no solution, solved with a workaround.

Comment: that is the same thing I am doing. I am using thumbnailator to translate a thumbnail of a bmp -> jpg.

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the upcoming 1.8.5 version, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2030 . It is already fixed in the 2.0 version (which has a different API), see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1990 . You can get both from svn.